# Why do functions and classes assigned to `window` not equal themselves in a GreaseMonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I have a class `Foo` with a static method that compares `this` to `Foo`, and for some reason the output of that comparison is `false`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     GreaseMonkey test
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include  *
// ==/UserScript==

window['Cls'] = class {};
window['func'] = function() {};

console.log(Cls === Cls);  // output: false
console.log(func === func);  // output: false
```

How can this be? I suspect it's related to the fact that Greasemonkey executes userscripts in a sandbox with elevated privileges, but even then I cannot understand why this would output `false`. Furthermore, the output changes to `true` if the function and the class aren't assigned to `window`:

```
class Cls {};
function func() {};

console.log(Cls === Cls);  // output: true
console.log(func === func);  // output: true
```

What is going on here?

Comment: This is really weird, wow. Can you also a) try with a `{}` object instead of a function b) try to evaluate the comparison multiple times (may it only returns something different on first access) c) log the values before comparing them?

Comment: GM 4+ is all kinds of fubar.  That's why I no longer support it.  Just tell your users to use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey, as [GM itself recommends](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).

Comment: Objects seem to behave as expected, they `===` each other and `===` the same thing on `window` and `unsafeWindow`

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm using GM 3.11, and the problem occurs there as well.

Comment: @Bergi a) `{}` objects compare equal to themselves. b) The result is `false` every time. c) logging the values yields the source code of the class/function, nothing unexpected. But I have discovered that the comparison returns `true` if I assign the class/function to a variable first: `var f = func; f === f // true`